# Pointer-to-member function resolution

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Here is a functor used to filter a list of objects. It must be instanciated with a pointer to member function of the objects' class, as a way to access different elements.

```
class Filter_Compare : public Filter {
    std::string (File::*fun)();
public:
    Filter_Compare(const char *name, const char *desc, std::string (File::*f)())
        : Filter(name, desc), fun(f)
    {}
    ~Filter_Compare() {};

    int operator () (File* f1, File* f2) { return this->eval(*f1, *f2); }
    int eval(File* f1, File* f2) const { return this->eval(*f1,*f2); }

    int eval(File& f1, File& f2) const {
        return f1.*(this->fun()).compare(f2.*(this->fun()));
    }
};
//an instanciation example :
Filter_Compare fname("Name", "Compare by name", File::getPath);
```

And g++ returns these error :

> Filter.h: In member function ‘int Filter_Compare::eval(File&, File&)
>   const’: Filter.h:48:27: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call
>   pointer-to-member function in ‘((const
>   Filter_Compare*)this)->Filter_Compare::fun (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->*
>   ((const Filter_Compare*)this)->Filter_Compare::fun) (...)’
>       Filter.h:48:53: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘((const
>   Filter_Compare*)this)->Filter_Compare::fun (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->*
>   ((const Filter_Compare*)this)->Filter_Compare::fun) (...)’

I don't see the problem here, as I've already used this on another class without any error (well, at least it compile, I couldn't run it right now), where the code is :

> lit_type eval(File& f) const {
>      return f.*(this->fun()) - thValue;
>   }

What exactly is wrong here ? I don't know how I could make a reference to the pointer another way. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parenthesis are wrong:

```
int eval(File& f1, File& f2) const {
    return (f1.*fun)().compare((f2.*fun)());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To call through a pointer-to-member-function you use `.*` or `->*`. To call `fun` on the `File& f1`, the call is `(f1.*fun)()`. So: `(f1.*fun)().compare((f2.*fun)())`. If you want to complexify the expression with explicit `this->`s that aren't needed, you have to be extra careful: `(f1.*(this->fun))().compare((f2.*(this->fun))())`.

Comment: I don't think you got the parenthesis right either. I believe it should be `(f1.*fun)()` (i.e. the `()` take precedence over `.*`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - you're probably right. That's what I get for not compiling the code. Fixed.